# Reading file in React action

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in javascript and have problem with it's asynchronous behavior. I am trying to read file in React action. Important part looks like this:

```
if(file){
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(inquiryFile);
    reader.onload = function() {
        body = JSON.stringify({
            fileToUpload: reader.result,
        });
        return dispatch(basicRequest(body));
    };
    reader.onerror = function(error) {
        console.error('Error uploadingFile: ', error);
    };
}
else{
    return dispatch(basicRequest());
}
```

The component, which is responsible for calling this action needs to dispatch another action depending on either success or error result.

```
return submitFileAction(masterId, data).then((result) => {
    if (!result.error) {
        console.log('success');
    } else {
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

Problem is, that result returning to 'then part' is undefined and filereader.onload is called after I get error.
I would like to ask how to await result from filereader.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to wrap the FileReader into a Promise.

```
if (file) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    ...
    reader.onload = function(){
      ...
      resolve(dispatch(basicRequest(body)));
    };
    reader.onerror = function(error) { reject(error); };
  });
}
```

The error would be handled as:

```
return submitFileAction(masterId, data).then((result) => {
  console.log('success'); 
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('error');
});
```

This presumes dispatch() also returns a Promise.